# Priority of hidden rules in Outlook/Exchange (2016/2010 respectively)

Tags: exchange-2010, rules, exchangeonline

We have recently moved from a purely Exchange 2010 environment, to a hybrid Exchange 2010/O365 environment and now are using EOP for spam filtering.

One user consistently has SCL level 5 tagged e-mails appear in his Inbox. This user also has a number of user-set rules in their mailbox.

I am having trouble finding any information about what priority is given to the hidden rule I am aware of that handles putting spam in the Junk Mail folder, or diverting it from it, so I can eliminate one of the user's rules having the "stop processing more rules" setting set which with that hidden rule having a priority lower than the user-set rules could explain this behaviour (though this would seem like a significant flaw in Microsoft's design of user/system mailbox management rules processing).

Running `Get-InboxRules` also shows server-side rule "contains errors", which I can conceivably think might also/instead be halting rules with a lower priority from running, perhaps including the aforementioned hidden rule.

Can anyone advise whether either hypothesis above seems reasonable, and perhaps point me to information I have tried to google for that provides more detail about how these hidden rules fit into the process of processing mail?

Answer (score 0):

According to your situation, it is suggested that deleting hidden inbox rules with MFCMAPI and server-side rule "contains errors", then recreating the rules.

**How to delete corrupted, hidden inbox rules from a mailbox using MFCMAPI**
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/hkong/2015/02/27/how-to-delete-corrupted-hidden-inbox-rules-from-a-mailbox-using-mfcmapi/

For the option "stop processing more rules", when it turns on, a message comes in that meets the criteria for more than one rule, only the first rule will be applied. Without this setting, all rules that the message meets the criteria for are applied.

You could put the rule higher in the "Rules and Alerts" list to modify the priority, and add the option to stop processing or not to your request.

Comment: Would prefer not throwing the baby out with the bath water, so to say. Besides, if user recreates rules exactly the same and my theory on hidden rules being processed after user rules this would lead us back to the same situation. Lastly, not sure my point about the processing order of rules is understood - The fact I have found that MS has decided to facilitate spam emails moving with the same mechanism as user created rules, just hidden from easy view, seems reasonable to me that they are processed (hopefully) prior to user ones, but could also be after. Which one is it?